# How to display Retina (32x32) favicons in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, retina-display

Using Chrome on my Retina MacBook Pro, I can't get the higher resolution (32x32) favicon on my blog to load first. When I first open the page (http://insofar.org), the 16x16 version is displayed and it is only on reload that the 32x32 shows up. As an alternative example, when loading [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net), its 32x32 favicon is loaded first. And yes, I cleared my cache.

In both cases, we're using the following tag in the head section:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/path/to/favicon.ico">
```

where favicon.ico contains both the 32x32 and 16x16 versions.

How can I force the 32x32 on Retina displays?

EDIT: I found that the issue is fixed in the latest Google Chrome Canary (v24.0.1300.0).

Comment: I wonder if the order of the images in the icon file makes any difference? It may be worth a try to switch them around and see if that helps. Although honestly I have no idea, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: We've thought of the same thing. I compared both favicon.ico files and in both cases, the 32x32 version appears first (at least in Preview.app on OS X).

Answer (score 2):

You should try Faviconer.com - designed for creating 16x16 and retina 32x32 favicon .ICO files. You can draw a new icon from scratch or you can upload any graphic image and convert it to .ICO format.

Here is the link - http://faviconer.com

Comment: Seems not allowing to import 32x32 images (only the top left part is fetched into 32 canvas)

Comment: @Pierre de LESPINAY Can import 32x32 images, no problems noticed with converting.

Comment: doesn't do alpha blends ... ugly jaggies if you have a png with alpha values

Answer (score 1):

For importation http://xiconeditor.com/ worked very well for me.
It creates ico with 16, 24, 32, 64 sizes.

I suggest to generate first your image with your editor in the different sizes then import each one in order to keep the quality.